# Zabbix Monitoring Tool Database Connection issue

Tags: mysql, connectivity, zabbix

I am trying to install Zabbix Monitoring server on Linux Cent OS 6.x. I have installed Zabbix 2.4 version on it. I have followed the following article of Zabbix to configure it:

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/installation/install_from_packages

Once I reach at IPAddress/zabbix at browser settings, I have successfully passed PHP settings and configuration stage.

But, when I go to next steps where I have to apply database settings, it is not working. However, I have created required database with permissions, and imported schemas too.

I have checked all required services and they are running fine too. Although I have restarted all the services, rebooted server many times.

Error Message:
Error in establishing database connection

Does anyone have solution of it?

Thanks,

Sandeep Gandhi

Comment: No one has solution of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php` file for `$DB['TYPE']` , `$DB['SERVER']`, `$DB['PORT']`, `$DB['DATABASE']`, `$DB['USER']` and`$DB['PASSWORD']` items.

Comment: Hi Ali Yousefi Sabzevar,

Yes, you have created my day..!!!

It is working like a charm..

Thanks a ton!!!